# Convert var latlng = $(this).attr('title') to usable coordinates for google map v3

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am trying to add a marker when a location title is clicked.  The title of the span contains the coordinates in the title format 43.61243.612631631, -116.21107599999999

When I run the following code it errors out.  If I actually type the coordinates in it works though.

```
$('.showmapmarker').click(function(){
    var latlng=$(this).attr('title'); 
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latlng),
    map: map
    });

});
```

I have searched all day, but maybe I need to convert latlng out of a string or something?  Any help is sure appreciated.  The rest of the map is standard v3 and works fine displaying markers, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to break it up. So split the string where the comma is at then put it in as (lat,long)

```
var latlngStr = $(this).attr('title'); 
var latlng= latlngStr.split(",");

new google.maps.LatLng(latlng[0], latlng[1])
```

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Cleaner solution for what I was trying to do.